# In c++ how to move range elements for a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array, move, stdvector

Say I have a:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > indices;
```

I fill these up, where each index of both outer and inner vectors have 3 entries. Now I want to do something similar to applying `std:move_backward()` on single vector-containers.

Let me give an example. Here is my initial container filled at the following indices:

```
[0][0][0][1][0][2] , [1][0][1][1][1][2] , [2][0][2][1][2][2] , [3][0][3][0][3][0]
```

After moving from an i-th element backwards, in this example: the outer-index `[1]`, I would get:

```
[0][0][0][1][0][2] , [1][0][1][1][1][2] , [1][0][1][1][1][2] , [2][0][2][1][2][2]
```

Basically, the outer-index `[1]` is placed in `[2]`, and `[3]` is replaced by the original `[2]`, moving the inner-vectors along with it.

Any ideas on how this can be done? Perhaps with a function template?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  What goes wrong when you use std::move_backward?

Comment: `move_backward` gives wrong/empty values, but `copy_backward` seems to do the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you describe:

```
std::copy_backward(indices.begin()+1, indices.begin()+3, indices.end());
```

No special manipulation of the inner vector is necessary.